# Convert any file to PNG in Java

Tags: java, rgba

I am wanting to convert any file to a PNG and also reverse the process, all in Java.

I want to use an int-RGB form for the image, and have bytes from the file be a byte in the RGB integer. This should produce an image.

I've gotten this to work by only storing the bytes in the red color, but I can't figure out how to also use green and blue.

This is the code I use at the moment, which only uses red, and it works fine:

```
public static void fileToImage(String sourceFile, String imageFile) throws IOException {
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(sourceFile));
    int size = ((int) Math.sqrt(dis.available())) + 2;
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(size,size, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    for (int y = 0; y < size; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
            int red = dis.read(); // I'm using only red
            int green = 0; // default
            int blue = 0; // default
            int rgb = (0xFF << 24) | ((red & 0xFF) << 16) | ((green & 0xFF) << 8) | (blue & 0xFF);
            image.setRGB(x, y, rgb);
        }
    }
    dis.close();
    ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File(imageFile));
}

public static void imageToFile(String imageFile, String outputFile) throws IOException {
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File(imageFile));
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outputFile));
    for (int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++) {
            int rgb = image.getRGB(x, y);
            int red = (rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
            int green = (rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
            int blue = rgb & 0xFF;
            dos.write(red); // I'm using only red
        }
    }
    dos.close();
}
```

EDIT: Okay, so I have modified the code, here it is:

```
public static void fileToImage(String sourceFile, String imageFile) throws IOException {
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(sourceFile));
    int size = ((int) Math.sqrt(dis.available())) + 2;
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(size,size, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    for (int y = 0; y < size; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
            int red = dis.read();
            int green = dis.read();
            int blue = dis.read();
            int rgb = (0xFF << 24) | ((red & 0xFF) << 16) | ((green & 0xFF) << 8) | (blue & 0xFF);
            image.setRGB(x, y, rgb);
        }
    }
    dis.close();
    ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File(imageFile));
}

public static void imageToFile(String imageFile, String outputFile) throws IOException {
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File(imageFile));
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outputFile));
    for (int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++) {
            int rgb = image.getRGB(x, y);
            int red = (rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
            int green = (rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
            int blue = rgb & 0xFF;
            dos.write(red);
            dos.write(green);
            dos.write(blue);
        }
    }
    dos.close();
}
```

This does "work", but not exactly as expected. There's a whole lot of black space in the produced PNG, because I believe the "size" of the image is wrong. Because of this, when translating the PNG back into the original file, it becomes much larger than originally.

EDIT: The issue I am now having is this: For example, if I turn a text file with the following content to a PNG using the fileToImage method: hello world! Then I use imageToFile to convert it back, the output is: hello world!SSSSSSSSSSSSSSS (S stands for "space", there are 15)

EDIT: Still can't figure this out. Here's what I'm using:

```
private static final int NAN = -1;

private static int readByte(DataInputStream dis) throws IOException {
    int b;
    try {
        b = dis.readByte();
    } catch (EOFException e) {
        b = NAN;
    }
    return b;
}

public static void fileToImage(String sourceFile, String imageFile) throws IOException {
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(sourceFile));
    int size = ((int) Math.sqrt(dis.available())) + 2;
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(size, size, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    for (int y = 0; y < size; y++) {
        boolean finished = false;
        for (int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
            int alpha = 3;
            int red = readByte(dis);
            int green = readByte(dis);
            int blue = readByte(dis);
            if (red == NAN) {
                alpha--;
                red = 0;
            }
            if (green == NAN) {
                alpha--;
                green = 0;
            }
            if (blue == NAN) {
                alpha--;
                blue = 0;
            }
            int rgb = ((alpha & 0xFF) << 24) | ((red & 0xFF) << 16) | ((green & 0xFF) << 8) | (blue & 0xFF);
            image.setRGB(x, y, rgb);
            if (alpha < 3) {
                finished = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (finished) break;
    }
    dis.close();
    ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File(imageFile));
}

public static void imageToFile(String imageFile, String outputFile) throws IOException {
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File(imageFile));
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outputFile));
    for (int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++) {
        boolean finished = false;
        for (int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++) {
            int rgb = image.getRGB(x, y);
            int alpha = (rgb >> 24) & 0xFF;
            int red = (rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
            int green = (rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
            int blue = rgb & 0xFF;
            if (alpha == 0) {
                finished = true;
                break;
            }
            if (alpha >= 1) dos.write(red);
            if (alpha >= 2) dos.write(green);
            if (alpha == 3) dos.write(blue);
        }
        if (finished) break;
    }
    dos.close();
}
```

Comment: I want to convert any file (EXE, JAR, etc.) into a PNG. I also want to convert it back.

Comment: And what *precisely* is the problem? What can't you figure out?

Comment: I am confused as to how to use red, green, and blue to store the bytes of the file. On how I'd do the iteration, is what confuses me the most.

@Voo what do you mean it doesn't generate a valid PNG? It is supposed to convert some converted file (a PNG) back into it's original form, so it should be generating a non-PNG.

Comment: @ThomasNappo: you currently read one byte and use it for the red value - why don't you read a second and third byte and use it for the green and blue values respectively? (Then you're left with the problem of the bytes needing to be in multiples of 3).

Comment: [InputStream#available](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available%28%29), does not do what you expect: Returns an **estimate** of the number of bytes that can be read from this input stream **without blocking**.

Comment: @GregKopff: I was going to do that. I don't know how to solve the problem of the bytes needing to be in multiples of 3. :-(

Comment: You could store each byte from the file in R, G, B, in turn, or you could _duplicate_ each byte's value into the R, G, B for each pixel, or any range of extremely complicated options. What are you hoping to accomplish by shoving random data into a png?

Comment: @sarnold: That's what I want to do. But I have no idea how to prevent the problem of byte in pairs of 3. What I'm trying to accomplish is kinda for "fun", but also for a private business idea.

Comment: *"but also for a private business idea."* If that business idea is 'protecting data from falling into the wrong hands' then this is a bad way to go about it.  Encryption would be a better strategy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to adjust the inner loops slightly. A small helper method will make this thing easier to use, thought I'm sure my sketch is a bit ugly:

```
int myReadByte(DataInputStream dis) {
    int b;
    try {
        b = dis.readByte():
    } catch (EOFException e) {
        b = 0;
    }
    return b;
}
```

Now with this helper...

```
for (int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
        int red = myReadByte(dis);
        int green = myReadByte(dis);
        int blue = myReadByte(dis);
        int rgb = (0xFF << 24) | ((red & 0xFF) << 16) | ((green & 0xFF) << 8) | (blue & 0xFF);
        image.setRGB(x, y, rgb);
```

and

```
for (int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++) {
        int rgb = image.getRGB(x, y);
        int red = (rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
        int green = (rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
        int blue = rgb & 0xFF;
        dos.write(red);
        dos.write(green);
        dos.write(blue);
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps the _second_ time the `DataInputStream` is called after running out of input it won't re-throw `EOFException` -- that helper may require more work. Still, I hope the sketch is useful.

Comment: The issue I am now having is this:

For example, if I turn a text file with the following content to a PNG using the _fileToImage_ method: _hello world!_

Then I use _imageToFile_ to convert it back, the output is: _hello world!SSSSSSSSSSSSSSS_ (S stands for "space", there are 15)

Comment: Ha! Figures, I write half an answer.. you'll also need to provide a marker when you're out of actual input so that the output routine knows when to ignore the "noise" bytes from the input or extra pixels left over to make the image rectangular. You could use the alpha channel (hard coded to `FF` here) to indicate which of the bytes contains useful data. It'll be a bit more complicated but _well_ worth the effort to fix.

Comment: A few quick thoughts: `myReadByte()` is poorly done -- it should _not_ return `0` for `EOFException` -- it should return `-1` or something else that cannot be in the data stream. You then use that value to determine if the red, green, or blue channel has data: Start with `FF`, subtract `1` if red does not have data, subtract `2` if green does not have data, and subtract `4` if blue does not have data. Then when you're decoding the png, look at the alpha channel: find the difference between `FF` and the alpha channel; it'll be between `0` and `7` -- an octal encoding of which bytes to ignore.

Comment: In _imageToFile_ method, when I do a stdout of alpha, it's 255??? But I write it as 3. I don't understand that, AT ALL.

Comment: Perhaps this new problem should be a new question; we've reached the limits of what can reasonably be discussed in one question, I think.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your code converts consecutive 3 bytes to one pixel. because of that you get only 1/3 of the file with color and the 2/3 rest are empty.

To fix that just divide the file size with 3.

```
int size = ((int) Math.sqrt(dis.available()/3)) + 2;
```